# www to non-www redirect in my site not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This questions has been asked many times on this site and I have tried most of them but nothing worked for me.

I have a site which works fine at http://example.com/ but when I apply ***rewritecond*** & ***rewriterule*** to redirect from www( http://www.example.com/ ) to non-www( http://example.com/ ), it's not working as expected.

I have tried the following solutions

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com [nc]
rewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

it works fine at http://example.com/ but show the following error at http://www.example.com/

> server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(.+)
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

It shows the same error as above.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off 
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

This shows the error

> To many redirects

Answer (score 0):

Error message says it all. Please add A record for www.example.com(Same IP as example.com) as well in DNS control panel.